# Comparing rpn (postfix) expressions for equivalency

Tags: python, postfix-notation, rpn

How would one compare any two postfix notated expressions for equivalency?

In the simplest example, foo(a, b) returns True for

```
a = [3, 5, 'MUL']

b = [5, 3, 'MUL']
```

What would `foo()` look like in python? I imagine that one way is to evaluate both expressions and normalize them somehow. I expect that this is a well defined process but haven't found it yet.

Edit 1:

This was a poorly worded question. I will try with better/more examples, and appreciate your patience as I try and ask the question clearly and precisely.

```
expr1 = [a, b, 'MUL']

expr2 = [b, a, 'MUL']
```

OR

```
expr1 = [a, b, 1, 'ADD', 'MUL']

expr2 = [a, b, 'MUL', a, 'ADD']
```

Comment: Do you have a function that calculates the notation? or are you asking here for someone here to help you create a code for that too?

Comment: I have code to evaluate the postfix expression. Adding to original question if it is useful.

Comment: can you add more example ?

Comment: Evaluating an expression and determining equivalency based on the output of one set of possible parameters doesn't seem robust (and I have nothing to back that statement up). Adding more evaluations will add to the time it takes if I have a lot of such comparisons to do. Is there another way to think about this problem/solution too?

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the postfix evaluation. you wcould have it like this then.

```
foo(a,b):
    res_a = postfix(a)
    res_b = postfix(b)
    if res_a = res_b:
         return True
    return False
```

I think this is the simplest solution you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Here I have tried your problem with a solution, it works , if you have more choices you can add :

```
a = [3, 5, 'MUL']
b = [5, 3, 'MUL']


def postfix_calc(value, z):
    return {
        'MUL': lambda c: a[0]*a[1],
        'ADD': lambda c: a[0]+a[1],
        'SUB': lambda c: a[0]-a[1],
        'DIV': lambda c: a[0]/a[1]
    }.get(value)(z)


def foo(x, y):
    val1 = postfix_calc(x[2], x)
    val2 = postfix_calc(y[2], y)
    if val1 == val2:
        return True
    else:
        return False


print(foo(a,b))
```